# Postgres function assign query results to multiple variables

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql

I need to assign values to 2 variable as below in Postgres function.

```
a := select col1 from tbl where ...
b := select col2 from tbl where ...
```

How can I assign 2 values to 2 variables in one line command?

Like

```
a,b := select col1,col2 from tbl where ...
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As said in  ["40.5.3. Executing a Query with a Single-row Result"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) (emphasis mine):

> The result of a SQL command yielding a single row (possibly of multiple columns) can be assigned to a record variable, row-type variable, or **list of scalar variables**. This is done by writing the base SQL command and adding an INTO clause.

So this should work:

```
SELECT col1, col2 INTO a, b FROM tbl WHERE...;
```