# How to write a comma-separated list of a single scalar variable in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

This is related to:

- [Postgres function assign query results to multiple variables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/54011/104401)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/15949337/5419599

I want to loop over values returned in a *single* column.

In other words:

```
FOR my_var IN select distinct some_column from some_table LOOP
  -- do stuff with my_var
END LOOP;
```

(The type of some_column is `text`, by the way.)

However, I get an error (line break added for readability):

```
ERROR:  loop variable of loop over rows must be a record
or row variable or list of scalar variables
```

---

I believe I can work around this with something like:

```
DECLARE
  somerow RECORD;
  my_var TEXT;
FOR somerow IN select distinct some_column from some_table LOOP
  my_var := somerow.somecolumn;
  -- do stuff with my_var
END LOOP;
```

Or perhaps even:

```
DECLARE
  idontcare INT;
  my_var TEXT;
FOR my_var, idontcare IN select distinct some_column, 1 from some_table LOOP
  -- do stuff with my_var
END LOOP;
```

---

But, isn't there any way I can just have a *single* variable in a comma-separated list?  Or is that impossible?

(If it's impossible, are the other workarounds I gave above even correct?  Any gotchas in them?)

Comment: I used the second workaround mentioned above.  Seems to operate as expected.